# Why are Lazy loaded relations not automatically set for bidirectional access

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an object hierarchy as follows where the collections are lazily loaded:

```
Object_1
    - List<Object_2>
        - Object_3
            - Object_4
```

Therefore, from Object_4 point of view it looks like this:

```
- Object_4
    - List<Object_3>
        - List<Object_2>
            Object_1
```

Objects are initialized as follows:

```
Object_1 object1 = em.find(...);
object1.getObjects2().forEach(o2 -> o2.getObjects3().size());
```

If I do now the following, a LazyInitializationException is thrown at the last line:

```
Object_2 object2 = object1.getObjects2().get(0);
Object_3 object3 = object2.getObject3();
Object_4 object4 = object3.getObject4();
em.getTransaction().commit();

Object_3 object3_1 = object4.getObjects3().get(0);
```

I would assume that it should be possible for the framework to have filled the List of Objects_3 with the objects loaded at line 2, because their one-to-one relation to object4 was resolved eagerly.

So, is it possible and I am e.g. missing some configuration? Am I missing something and my assumption is wrong? Or is it simply not implemented this way?

Comment: mark your method with `@Transactional` it should help

Comment: 1. Your hierarchy is wrong - `object2.getObjects3()` returns a list and in your example it is a single `Object_3`. 2. If you access `object2.getObjects3()` the table for `Object_3` is queried for all objects that relate to the single `object2` and also their eagerly loaded `Object_4` are loaded - but as each `Object_4` can refer to a list of `Object_3` you assume that JPA loads the other `Object_3` rows that are not related to the respective `object2` you started your navigation with.

Comment: @Smutje 1. correct, I've edited it accordingly. 2. From my understanding it would not be neccessary that all Object_3s are loaded that relate to Object_4, but that the given Object_3 is added to the list within Object_4.

Comment: But then the object graph would be inconsistent and I don't want to think about possible implications this would have to other use-cases - e.g. once a list has been populated how should JPA know if it should extend the list and so on.

Comment: @Smutje If the collection was a Set it should not matter to add the same object multiple times. Anyway, your explaination sounds reasonable. The reason for the question is, I'm dealing with an old rusty application and on one hand it's difficult to read everything at once, because it's almost impossible to know what exactly is needed later on, on the other hand people are afraid it might impact performance if stuff is read everywhere it is needed.

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I don't think that will work, because the query is within an EJB and leaving it will close the transaction. Hence the LazyInitException.